# clojure nrepl in emacs saving state - always evaluating entire file on nrepl-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, nrepl

I'm using emacs live to set up my clojure environment. 1) What command would cause nrepl to try and evaluate the entire file upon jack-in? 2) Is there some place where session state is saved?

For some unknown reason emacs is now trying to evaluate the entire clojure file when I execute M-x nrepl-jack-in. It used to not do that. I have an error in my file and, since the execution fails, I can't start nrepl with this file. This is not the first time I've run into some semantics that change. I've tried restarting emacs but that doesn't help.

Thanks

Comment: What file is being loaded? What is the specific error? For example if project.clj was malformed, that should prevent jack-in from working. Are you able to jack-in from a directory with no clojure project (this should provide a generic clojure repl with minimal deps as provided by lein repl in a projectless directory).

Comment: If I have any clj file previously loaded in a buffer and I try jack-in it now tries to execute the clj file. If there's an error in that file then the nrepl-server fails to start. I see the file error printed but I don't see the nrepl error. The directory emacs was started from is the home directory and it is not a project directory. If there is no clj file in a buffer then jack-in works fine. It used to not do this so I don't know what changed.

Comment: The directory you jack-in from is not the directory emacs was started from. The default directory for any emacs buffer is the directory of that buffer's file (if any). You need to be visiting a file in your home directory (or dired of the directory yourself) to be sure you are jacking in from the home directory.

Comment: It sounds like you're right. I fixed the errors and jack-in doesn't cause any errors. If I call jack-in while the cursor is in the clj file it executes the file. If I call it from *scratch* it doesn't. If I put an error back in and call from that pane it finds the error. Thank you. Write up the obvious result and I'll give you the star.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nrepl`'s `jack-in` behavior is dependent on the location of the file backing the buffer you are visiting when you invoke the `jack-in` command.

To get a vanilla no-project repl, be sure to run `nrepl-jack-in` from a buffer where there is no Clojure project. To run a repl in a specific project via jack-in, run it while visiting a file in the top level of that project (`project.clj` is a prime cantidate).